# Query to check if size of collection is 0 or empty in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

`Person` has one `Building`.

`Person` has many `Group`

I want to return all of the `people` from a certain `building` who do not have any `Group` in their `groups` collection.
 Maybe I can search by people who have a group list that has a length of 0?
Something like:

```
unassigned=Person.query.filter(Person.building==g.current_building,Person.groups.any()).all()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use negation (`~`) with [`any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any):

```
q = session.query(Person)
q = q.filter(Person.building == g.current_building)
q = q.filter(~Person.groups.any())
```

`any` is more powerful than needed in your case, but it will do the job just fine.

Comment: Is this "expensive" because of the power of any?

Comment: I do not think it is going to be expensive, but as often is the case: it depends: it might be faster or slower than other solutions depending on your data density, database indices present and, of course, the RDBMS itself. `any` will generate a sub-query though so it is not a "nice" piece of SQL, but here this is what SA is hiding from the user.

Comment: Using an outer join is more than 100 times as fast (I didn't wait for the `any()` version to finish) as `any()` in my similar case on a 5Gb sqlite database: `session.query(Ebook.id).outerjoin(Sentence).filter(Sentence.id == None)`

Answer (score 0):

First count the groups per building, then filter on that count.

```
gc = session.query(
    Person.id,
    db.func.count(Group.id).label('gc')
).join(Person.groups).group_by(Person.id).subquery()

unassigned = session.query(Person).join(
    (gc, gc.c.person_id == Person.id)
).filter(
    Person.building == g.current_building,
    gc.c.gc == 0
).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know if a relation have records after the query use the `count()` method on the relation:

```
persons = session.query(Person).filter(Person.building == g.current_building).all()
for p in persons:
    if p.groups.count():
        print("%s have groups" % p)
```